# ¿Cómo puedo convertir un archivo svg animado en un archivo de video o varios archivos de imagen (fotograma por fotograma)?

Tags: svg

Quiero convertir un archivo .svg animado en un video como .mp4, .mkv, etc. o en varios archivos de imagen fotograma por fotograma ya sea .png, .jpg. etc.
He encontrado este [artículo](http://www.dzejkobgames.eu/capturing-svg-frames-with-advanced-effects) donde tienen un programa exitoso, pero no sé cómo y en dónde ejecutarlo con mi propia imagen.

¿Alguien conoce de alguna herramienta que me permita convertir mi imagen, si no alguien conoce como ejecutar el programa del artículo que encontré con mi propia imagen?

> Disculpen si es una duda algo estúpida pero yo no conozco nada de html, css y xml

Comment: Bienvenido a SOes te recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y ganes tu primera medalla! Además te recomiendo que leas [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: La primera entra de la consulta en google ya te indica un sitio web para hacerlo en linea: https://www.google.com/search?q=svg+to+avi